# Passing the security_token for ec2 creation - BOTO

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, boto, botocore

I have the accesskey, secret access key and security token for my session and am trying to create a ec2 instance using BOTO:

```
import boto
from boto.vpc import VPCConnection

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1", aws_security_token = "xx", aws_access_key_id= "xx",  aws_secret_access_key= "xx")
```

as I run the script, I get the error =

> return self.connection_cls(region=self, **kw_params) TypeError:
>   **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aws_security_token'

Not sure why I am getting this error, is there an alternate way of passing the security token?

Comment: what is the aws_security_token? I think your code will work fine if you just remove that key:value

Comment: I dont want to remove the aws_security_token. Its the session token for temporary access, without which AWS doesnt authorize me. I need to pass it somehow and this:http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_snapshot_module.html suggested I could pass it as environment variables but alas.

Comment: I think the parameter is just ``security_token``, not ``aws_security_token``.